# how can we do pivoting without using aggregate function?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

i would like to do pivoting without sql aggregate function.
Here 'max' aggregate function has been used but when i removed aggregate function then syntax error is shown. When i used the 'max' aggregate function then only the largest string among string values is shown and when 'min' aggregate function  is used then minimum string value among string is shown. I need both minimum and maximum , all  string values from 'FieldSubValues'.

I need to do pivoting  without use of aggregate function. Can anyone help me.

```
SELECT   *  
FROM
(
     SELECT FieldSubName,FieldSubValues 
    FROM FormFieldValue where FieldID=182 
)as p    
PIVOT 
( 
    min(FieldSubValues) 
    FOR FieldSubName IN ([Name],[Gender],[Days],[Message]) 
) AS pvt
```

Here i want both the 'Message' value i.e 'Testing' and 'fsdfds'
[image]

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't make sense. You can't have *two* (or more) values in a single column of one row.

Comment: Please post the expected results of the query.

Comment: I want to pivot FieldSubName column values and  all the field values of 'FieldSubValues' columns  to respective pivoted columns i.e Name,Gender,Days and Message. The pivoted 'FieldSubName' columns value must contains all the values of 'FieldSubValues' column, not only minimum and maximum values

Answer (score 2):

If you need both `Min()` and `Max()` string values, you can just use a `UNION` to `PIVOT` twice.

```
select *
from 
(
  select FieldSubName, FieldSubValues
  from FormFieldValue
) x
PIVOT
(
  min(FieldSubValues)
  for FieldSubName IN ([Name], [Gender], [Days], [Message])
) p
UNION
select *
from 
(
  select FieldSubName, FieldSubValues
  from FormFieldValue
) x
PIVOT
(
  max(FieldSubValues)
  for FieldSubName IN ([Name], [Gender], [Days], [Message])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1643d/2).

If you want all of the values not just the `max`/`min` values, then you could add a `row_number()` to the subquery.  By adding a row number you can partition the data over the FieldName which would allow you to pivot multiple rows - not just the max and min:

```
select [Name], [Gender], [Days], [Message]
from 
(
  select FieldSubName, FieldSubValues,
    row_number() over(partition by FieldName order by FieldId) seq
  from FormFieldValue
) x
PIVOT
(
  max(FieldSubValues)
  for FieldSubName IN ([Name], [Gender], [Days], [Message])
) p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1643d/14)

Comment: this above 'union' gives both minimum and maximum value but what if i want all the values not only minimum and maximum values, and how to do it